# How to get more verbose output from Scons

Tags: scons

How should I change SConstruct in order to see the details of how each file is compiled?

Currently, scons only outputs a bunch of 'compiling xxx.c ...'.

Comment: I always get the compiler command line when using g++ on linux: http://pastebin.com/QP8n93vA What language/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc on Fedora 17.

Comment: Likely this output is due to the build logic for whatever package you've downloaded and are building.  SCons by default will output the command lines for most (if not all) build steps.

Comment: What package are you trying to build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with an SConstruct file to do:

```
SetOption('silent')
```

which will suppress the output of any command. Is it possible you have one of these floating around somewhere?

Addendum:
You can also set the `CCOMSTR` variable to override the build message for C compiles (there's a different variable for each builder though),  and there's even a (not terribly well documented) `PRINT_CMD_LINE_FUNC` variable which would provide a general override.